# What is the MYSQL Query to bulk update the canonical URL of specific categories of posts in WordPress?

Tags: mysql

Thanks in advance for helping with this question. What is the MYSQL Query to bulk update the canonical URL of specific categories of posts in WordPress ?

Comment: The canonical URL for posts is not stored in the database. It's constructed from the site URL, permalink structure and post slug. What about the URL do you need to change?

Comment: I don't need to change the URL. I just wanted to point all canonical URLs in a certain category to a specific URL. Since many pages under a certain category are thin content.